# How to stop a node.js server without killing the process?

Tags: node.js

Say a server is created like:

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer();
server.listen(32323, '127.0.0.1');

server.close(); // gives a "not running" error if there is IP in the listen statement
```

is there a way to stop it from node.js, e.g. without ending/killing the whole process?

Also, here's a more complicated example that doesn't stop regardless of the IP the server is bound to:

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.on('data', console.log);
    server.close();
});

server.listen(32323);

var socket = net.createConnection(32323);
socket.write('hi');
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[`server.close`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_server_close_callback)

Do not call close before the `"listening"` event fires.

Either add a callback to `listen` or add an event manually

```
server.listen(port, host, function () { server.close(); });
// OR
server.on("listening", function () { server.close(); });
server.listen(port, host);

var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.on('data', console.log);
    server.close();
});

server.listen(32323);

var socket = net.createConnection(32323);
// call end to make sure the socket closes
socket.end('hi');
```

Comment: I don't get it. In the second snippet of mine, I call `close` after I have received the message, so clearly the server has been listening at that point. Could you please fix my second example, so that the server closes right after it receives the first message?

Comment: In the second example, after the message is received and `server.close` is called, node's process is still running

Comment: @Fluffy that's because you didn't close the socket. Make sure you call `.end`

Answer (score 4):

Skipping to the 2nd, more realistic case: close the current connection before calling `server.close`:

```
var net = require('net')

var server = net.createServer(function(socket){
    socket.on('data', function(data){
        console.log(data.toString())
        socket.destroy()
        server.close()
    })
})

server.listen(32323)
```

Note that if you don't have any other server instances or activity going on in this process it will quit after closing `server`.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a HTTP or HTTPS server, it helps if you close the socket of the request with the following:

```
function onRequest(request, response) {
    response.end(); //close the response
    request.connection.end(); //close the socket
    request.connection.destroy; //close it really
    server.close(); //close the server
}

server.on("request", onRequest);
server.on("close", function() {console.log("closed");});

server.listen(port, host);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example demonstrating what I think you're after.

```
var net = require('net');


var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
  socket.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log("server got data " + data.toString());

  });
});

function startServer() {
  server.listen(32323, function () {
    console.log('server started');
  });
}

function stopServer() {
  server.close(function () {
    console.log('server stopped');
  });
}

setInterval(function () {

  if (server.address()) {
    console.log("Server is running on port " + server.address().port + " let's kill it.");
    stopServer();
  } else {
    console.log("Server is stopped let's start it.");
    startServer();
  }

}, 10000);


setInterval(function () {

  var socket = net.createConnection(32323, function () {
    socket.write('hi');
  });
  socket.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  });


}, 1000);

startServer();
```

Answer (score 0):

*server.close()* prevents new connections and waits until all the clients are closed.

To forcibly kill a node server you need to call server.close() and then close all the open connections from the server end.

When a client connects keep track of the socket.

```
var sockets = []

var server = net.createServer((socket) => {
   sockets.push(socket)
})
```

To forcibly kill ...

```
server.close()
sockets.forEach( (s) => s.end() )
```